# How do I deep link to Netflix on tvOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, tvos, netflix

I'm hoping to open a deep link to a show or movie in the Netflix app on the new 4th gen Apple TV.

I'm able to make deep linking work on iOS. The link below will open the Netflix app to a specific show or movie.

```
nflx://title/{showID}
for house of cards it's: nflx://title/70178217
```

When I try the same format on Apple TV, all that happens is the Netflix app opens without opening a specific show or movie. Siri search can open the app directly to a media item, so it seems like there should be a way for this to work.

Comment: Have you got a way to create a link that also can specify resume playback timestamp, like 2 min 3 sec?

Answer (score 18):

Figured this out. Turns out you can use the regular netflix url structure, but replace http with nflx.

```
nflx://www.netflix.com/title/70291117 - Will open a show page
nflx://www.netflix.com/watch/70291117 - Will begin playing the video
```